# Limit n tends to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, complex-numbers

How can i solve this:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos(1)\cos(0.5)\cos(0.25)\ldots \cos(1/2^n)
$$

I tried using comlex numbers and logarithms but did'nt work out.Can anyone help please.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455995/finding-the-limit-lim-limits-n-to-infty-cos-frac-x-2-cdot-cos-frac

Answer (score 2):

hint: multiply $sin \dfrac{1}{2^n}$

Comment: Brilliant hint. Why this post was reported as low quality is beyond me...

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\sin(x) = 2 \sin(x/2) \cos(x/2) = 2^2\sin(x/4) \cos(x/2) \cos(x/4) = \ldots = 2^n \sin(x/2^n)\prod_{k=1}^n \cos(x/2^k)
$$
Hence,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{k=1}^{n} \cos(x/2^k) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{2^n \sin(x/2^n)} = \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x/2^n}{\sin(x/2^n)}
$$
Now use the fact that
$$
\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{\sin(z)}{z} = 1
$$
Now plug in $x=1$.

Comment: so answer is sin1 ?

Comment: very cool answer

Answer (score 0):

We have the infinite product expansion

$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\prod _{k=1}^\infty \cos\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right)$$

This [result](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html) was first found by Francois Viète in 1593. For a proof, see also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107144/rigorous-proof-of-an-infinite-product) math.se question.